# Point location of excel data connection to a new directory for multiple files

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that has data connections to multiple delimited text files, which are periodically updated.  When they update, I refresh in excel, the whole spreadsheet updates, and I feel like a data wizard.

Here's the thing, I'm about to change my file structure, and currently my links are

```
oldpath\file1.txt
oldpath\file2.txt
oldpath\file3.txt
oldpath\file4.txt
oldpath\file5.txt  
etc.
```

Is there a way to point all the data connections to

```
newpath\file1.txt
newpath\file2.txt
newpath\file3.txt
etc.
```

Without editing the locations of each individual connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*xlsx* files are XML files compressed in a zip.

Based on that you can do this:

1. Unzip *file.xlsx* and extract everything to a empty directory, for example **test_directory**.
2. Inside *test_directory* open with a text editor the file  `xl/connections.xml`.
3. Modify with a *find/replace* `oldpath` to `newpath` in the file and save it.
4. Go back to the root of *test_directory*, select all and *zip* it.
5. Change the .zip extension to .xlsx extension.
6. Open it and test it.

Comment: I like this answer, I'll have a go

Comment: @Some_Guy Good luck *data wizard*.

Comment: feeling like a data wizard is a good feeling

Comment: I don't suppose you do know a GUI solution, for plebs?

Comment: @Some_Guy No. Excel doesnt provide a way to batch-change them.